# Client Server VS Observer Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, client-server, observer-pattern

Well I am wondering that why client-server architecture is not implementing Observer pattern ?

Well in **my** point of view:

> Client-Server is (kind-of) super-set of Observer design pattern like
>   client and server follow (kind-of) pull/push style !!

If client-server architecture NOT implementing Observer Design Pattern then **SHOULD** or **CAN** it follow Observer Pattern ? Please explain why or why not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Client-server is a generic model where you have a client requesting a resource and a server which responds. That's all. A DNS query or a web request is a perfect example of that. However there are occasions  where the client should be notified in real time for a change in server data. If this is the case we have two options:

- Pull model where we have the client send a request at a specific interval asking the server for changes.
- Push model where we have the server send back a notification to the client

Those two methods, are ways of implementing the (distirbuted) observer design pattern. However observer and client-server has nothing to do with each other. On top of a client-server architecture you may or may not implement a push/pull mechanism depending on the requirements.